# How to make a HTML Email format correctly whichever inbox it goes to?

Tags: html, email

having an absolute nightmare with my first attempt at creating a HTML Email. I designed this in photoshop and then sliced the document and exported for web. I have played about with the coding to make it work on hotmail, gmail etc which is fine but I can't get it to work on Outlook. What is wrong with my coding that isn't allowing the email to be received nicely everywhere....
    [Outlook Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z6qy.png)
    
    
    IGS Template Refinish HTML Test
    
    
    table {border-spacing: 0;}

```
<img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IGS-Template-Refinish-HTML-Test_07.gif" width="275" height="50" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;"></a></td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/spacer.gif" width="1" height="50" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="6">
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IGS-Template-Refinish-HTML-Test_09.gif" width="275" height="487" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/spacer.gif" width="1" height="236" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/pg-automotive" target="- Blank">
            <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IGS-Template-Refinish-HTML-Test_10.gif" width="222" height="44" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;"></a></td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/PGAutomotiveUK/" target="- Blank">
            <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IGS-Template-Refinish-HTML-Test_11.gif" width="51" height="44" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;"></a></td>
    <td>
        <a href="https://plus.google.com/106664683502244120701/about" target="- Blank">
            <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IGS-Template-Refinish-HTML-Test_12.gif" width="63" height="44" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;"></a></td>
    <td>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/pg-automotive" target="- Blank">
            <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IGS-Template-Refinish-HTML-Test_10-14.gif" width="83" height="44" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;"></a></td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/spacer.gif" width="1" height="44" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IGS-Template-Refinish-HTML-Test_14.gif" width="222" height="65" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/pgautomotive"> 
            <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IGS-Template-Refinish-HTML-Test_15.gif" width="51" height="65" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;"></a></td>
    <td>
        <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pgautomotive/" target="- Blank">
            <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IGS-Template-Refinish-HTML-Test_16.gif" width="63" height="65" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;"></a></td>
    <td>
        <a href="https://instagram.com/pgautomotive">
            <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IGS-Template-Refinish-HTML-Test_17.gif" width="83" height="65" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;"></a></td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/spacer.gif" width="1" height="65" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IGS-Template-Refinish-HTML-Test_18.gif" width="419" height="85" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/spacer.gif" width="1" height="85" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IGS-Template-Refinish-HTML-Test_19.gif" width="254" height="57" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <a href="mailto:lyndsey@pgautomotive.com" >
            <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IGS-Template-Refinish-HTML-Test_20.gif" width="165" height="11" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;"></a></td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/spacer.gif" width="1" height="11" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/IGS-Template-Refinish-HTML-Test_21.gif" width="165" height="46" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/spacer.gif" width="1" height="46" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/spacer.gif" width="222" height="1" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/spacer.gif" width="32" height="1" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/spacer.gif" width="19" height="1" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/spacer.gif" width="63" height="1" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/spacer.gif" width="83" height="1" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/spacer.gif" width="275" height="1" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.pgautomotive.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/spacer.gif" width="106" height="1" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices --> 
</body>
```

Comment: Can you give details and possibly screenshots as to how exactly your email doesn't render as intended in Outlook?

Comment: This is not easy, you can see supported features in different clients here https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Hello. Thanks for that link it if very useful. I'm not to this forum. how can i send you a screenshot? It looks fine until the bottom signature and one column is moved up a row. so half is out of sync. Thanks

Comment: Edit your question, there is a button in the editor for adding a picture.

Comment: Please see attached "outlook image" link. Thanks

Comment: @CandyGumdrop please see attached "outlook image" link. Thaks